# Where are logs stored when connecting (or failing to do so) to a file server?

Tags: networking, 18.04, file-sharing

I have a user running Ubuntu. When they are in the office, connected directly to the local network, they are unable to connect to a file server just down the hall from there office. To do so, he must connect first connect to our company's VPN.
I'd like to find the logs for this connection attempt to hopefully shine light on what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to a Samba share, then you may find some information in the `/var/log/syslog` file. When connecting to a network share, something like this will be recorded in the log:

```
Feb  3 15:04:56 Carbon kernel: [ 2364.612766] CIFS: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3.1.1), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3.1.1 (or even SMB3 or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
Feb  3 15:04:56 Carbon kernel: [ 2364.612770] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.0.241\Archives
```

If there is an error, it will appear shortly after this sort of line.

Comment: Thanks, it is samba share. I should have specified. The user just sent the me contents of /var/log/syslog but there is no entry for the attempt at connecting to the file server

Comment: How do they connect via the VPN? Is it by clicking the server from a list in Files? Is there a command or script that needs to run to mount the samba share? 

Comment: I meant to update earlier but the root issue is a DNS problem. The user could connect using the IP address, instead of hostname. I should mention they didn't see any logs in /var/log/syslog both times.